# Stubs for knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have written an application using knockout.js and I want to run the application in batch mode as well (e.g. using node.js).

This is a simulation application so the interactive, visual version is bound to an html front-end, but in addition I want to run the simulation in batch mode and generate masses of data for statistical analysis, so in that mode I want all the ko code to go away, since I don't need it and don't want to incur the performance overhead.

Example with visualization:

```
function Queue() {
  var self = this; 
  self.items = ko.observableArray();
  self.rate = ko.observable(5);
  ...
}

...
queue.rate(7);
```

Same in batch mode:

```
function Queue() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = [];
  self.rate = 5;
}

...
queue.rate = 5;
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

I was thinking of creating a stub for ko which removes the subscription-related logic, but perhaps there's an easier way?

Comment: Another reason for shunting ko is that it won't run as is under node as it depends on a DOM being present...

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use `ko.toJS(myObject)` to get a "clean" version of your object, but you would still incur some overhead creating the observables that you are ultimately just unwrapping to get a clean object.

My thought would be to create a stub for ko, as you said, that would simply return the value passed to it, if your goal is to share code between the two.

Comment: Thanks RP. I will try to create stubs for ko.

Comment: any suggestion on how I could create a stub for an observableArray?

Comment: Not sure of your exact structure, but do you need more than: `ko.observableArray = function(initialValue) {  return initialValue || []; };`

Comment: This is close but it does not support the () notation, e.g. `var arr = ko.observableArray(); ... var first_elem = arr()[0];`

Comment: If you just need to support operations like that, then you could do something like: ko.observableArray = function(initialValue) { initialValue = initialValue || []; return function() { return initialValue; } };   If you need to be able to set the value or call array operations (push/pop), then you need to go further with it.  If that is the case, then I can provide a sample. It would start getting pretty close to the actual implementation though.

Comment: Unfortunately I do need the array ops and the function notation since both are used. I tried implementing this but so far without success. If you can provide a sample that would be massively helpful.